# Classical Mechanics Video Lessons (for the Elderly)

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, education

A friend of mine (**way older** than me) has been following *The Theoretical Minimum* video lessons by Leonard Susskind. I have read all the questions here about resources on Classical Mechanics and note that I am not searching for books, but just video lectures.

Now, he'd like some more.

Specifically, he enjoyed the Classical Mechanics lessons (Lagrangian, Hamiltonian) and before moving to GR he wants to follow some deeper lessons.

I have no idea if and where such video (free) lessons could be found, and if they are at par with Susskind's lectures. My only concern is not to suggest a course (or some courses) that assumes too much knowledge from the spectator (I don't think he knows anything about differential geometry, for example, but I know he could manage to follow additional courses).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (v3) as off-topic because it seems to be a futile task to maintain up-to-date lists of pure video resources on Phys.SE. Users can recommend videos in answers to other res. recom questions, but separate video  res. recom. threads in various topics seem too much.

Comment: If he is elder i would recommend him the Feynmann Lectures....... Sure there should be video versions of them.